# Using USDA REST API

Tags: javascript, api, meteor

I can't seem to figure out how to use USDA REST API no matter how hard I try. I've taken about 6 different online tutorials on how to use REST APIs all of which do not work with this particular API (I'm sure it's something small I'm missing but I've wasted countless hours doing/watching tutorials with no success).

Here's the link to their API: 
https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/apilist/API-FOOD-REPORT.md

Here's what I'm typing in my JavaScript:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/", true);
console.log(xhr.status);
```

The API says to pass your API KEY in parameters, but that makes no sense to me as every single tutorial I have read does not explain how to pass a KEY as a parameter... If someone would mind taking a moment to write the code necessary to access this API I would be greatly indebted.

**UPDATE:** I've also tried the JQuery method as follows:

```
$.get(
    "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports",
    {
        "api_key": "API KEY",
        "ndbno": "01009"
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

With no luck.

**UPDATE 2:** After leaving the JQuery example in for about 5 minutes, I get an error in the chrome console that says:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports?api_key=(my API KEY)&ndbno=01009. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

**FINAL UPDATE:** Problem was with my ISP apparently. Need to deal with that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you reference has a sample request URL:

http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=b&format=xml&api_key=DEMO_KEY

You just need to replace the ndbno, type, format and api_key values (the bits that come after the "=").  For instance if your API key was 12345, you would need to change it like so:

http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=b&format=xml&api_key=12345

A complete, albeit "poor", implementation would be:

```
var apiKey = "DEMO_KEY";
var ndbno = "01009";
var type = "b";
var format = "json";

var url = "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=" + ndbno + "&type=" + type + "&format=" + format + "&api_key=" + apiKey;

$.get(url, function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + JSON.stringify(data) );
});
```

Comment: I saw that. But I have no idea what to do with that in my Javascript. Can you give me a XMLHttpRequest example? I types it in as such:

xhr.open("GET", "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=b&format=xml&api_key=API KEY", true);

But nothing happened at all. How are params supposed to be passed?

Comment: Also, if I enter it in just like you said: 

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=b&format=json&api_key=[API KEY]", true);
console.log(xhr.status);

My console.log returns "0".
I am not sure what that means but that is not good from what I've read.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for taking the time thus far. I appreciate it. Unfortunately that is exactly what my first attempt was entered. It console logs "0".

Comment: Try that, but obviously use your api key

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you were also using jQuery, that would makes things a lot easier...

Comment: Tried again using your clip, using my API Key, still getting same issue. If I change it to FALSE, I get this error in the console:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113191/discussion-between-chriskgregory-and-blakeh).

Comment: @chriskgregory do you know of any implementation of a reader/parser once the report is downloaded  ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'DEMO_KEY' provided by USDA I can get back a JSON result using the following code pasted into an HTML file (based on code from your on-going discussion with @BlakeH):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
    $.get(
        "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports",
        {
            "api_key": "DEMO_KEY",
            "ndbno": "01009"
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log( JSON.stringify(data, null, '    '))
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

No issues with CORS were encountered with this code.

Is there any chance that you submitted more than 1000 requests in the past 24 hours?

Comment: I think there's a problem with my internet. Blake was able to get JSON back and using the same code I am unable. I need to try when I'm at work tomorrow to decide whether or not that's the problem. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try hitting the API directly with your browser at: http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=b&api_key=DEMO_KEY  -- my expectation is that this will also not work for YOU on your current connection.  If it works you should see the JSON right in the browser.

Comment: Correct. It does not work for this connection. Windows 10 is killing me :( 

Thank you though!